# How to fix? TypeError: 'HTTPConnection' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently having a bit of trouble figuring out what python wants from me, help would be much appreciated :D

```
    def enumerator(self):
    system('clear')
    host = input("Host: ")
    port = 80
    conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(host, port)


    fileEnum = ["/admin", "/phpmyadmin", "/login", "/register", "/admin.php", "/register.php", "/info.php", "/wp-admin.php", "/admin/", "/install/"]
    conn(host, port,[10])
    conn.getresponse()
    if http.client.HTTPResponse == http.client.HTTPException:
        sys.exit(http.client.HTTPException)
    else:
        for x in range(len(fileEnum)):
            conn.request("GET", fileEnum[x], [10])
            r1 = conn.getresponse()
            if r1.status == 200:
                print(fileEnum[x] + "\n Directory/File found")

    return
```

Comment: `conn(host, port,[10])` <- that's a call attempt on an `HTTPConnection` object right there. The error says you can't do that.

Comment: How would you recommend I go about fixing this?

Comment: You need to look at the documentation of `HTTPConnection` objects and find a method which does what you think the direct call on the object does. Probably something with connecting.

Comment: fixed it i think, for some reason it didnt like being called by conn, changed it from conn to http.client.HTTPConnection. (possibly variable value interference??

Comment: You are confusing the construction of an object with a call on an object. `HTTPConnection(host, port)` (calling the class) will _construct_ an object. Calling that object (i.e. `conn(host, port)`) only works if the objects themselves are callable. Anyway, no problem :) Since your question is down to a mistake that is unlikely to help future readers I suggest deleting your question. You can do this without repercussions as long as there are no votes or answers on the question.